# SQL find the difference in days between two case statements partitioned by users

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Say I have a table like this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/800cb5

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `bow` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `eow` int(6) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`user_id`, `created_at`, `bow`, `eow`) VALUES
 ('1', '2019-01-01', '0', '1'),    
  ('1', '2019-01-02', '1', '1'),   
  ('1', '2019-01-03', '1', '1'),    
  ('1', '2019-01-05', '1', '0'),   
  ('2', '2019-01-11', '1', '1'),
  ('1', '2019-02-01', '0', '1'),    
  ('1', '2019-02-02', '1', '1'),   
  ('1', '2019-02-03', '1', '0');
```

If the "bow" is equal to 0 when the "eow" is equal to 1, I want to start counting days. I want to stop counting when "bow" equals 1 and "eow" equals 0, then take the number of days between these two values.

So my output would be:

```
(`user_id`, `created_at`, `days`)
('1', '2019-01-05', '4')
('1', '2019-02-03', '2')
```

as there are 4 days between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-05 and 2 days between 2019-02-01 and 2019-02-03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions -- specifically a cumulative conditional `max()` to get the previous date.

Then just filter for where the period ends:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(created_at, prev_created_at)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when bow = 0 and eow = 1 then created_at end) over (order by created_at) as prev_created_at
      from transactions t
     ) t
where bow = 1 and eow = 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c550839d2c7885e78d87bf43615edbf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Just what I was looking for